# Onclick change top position doesnt do anything

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, absolute

I think the problem's already stated. When you click the plus extra content is show(the Hello Guest and Register and Signup). Is their a better and working way of doing this or do I have a bug. New at java-script so don't hate.
---> http://jsfiddle.net/CM9Av/

Comment: We wont hate you if you'll please add your code in question itself :) Use fiddle for demo purposes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the top . Also, cache your variables.

```
function menuanimate() {
    var loginoutbox = document.getElementById("loginoutbox");
    var fromtop = loginoutbox.style.top;
    if (fromtop == "-20px") {
        fromtop = "0px";
    }
    else {
        fromtop = "-20px";
    }
    loginoutbox.style.top = fromtop;
}​
```

In markup , set `top` in inline style. `stlye.top` wont read css property.

```
<div id="loginoutbox" class="ablack" style='top:-20px'></div>
```

Try outside fiddle in a simple webpage. It works !

Demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ6mL/1/) (I dont know how to put pure js in fiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

You can not just update the variable fromtop, that will have no effect on the page. You will have to update the top-value manually, the same way you read it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function menuanimate(){

document.getElementById("loginoutbox").style.top="0px";
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#image{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:80%;
}
#image:hover{cursor:pointer;}
#loginoutbox{
left: 80%;
width: 218px;
color: white !important;
position: fixed;
top: -20px;
background-color: #444;
height: 20px;
text-align: right;
}
</style>

<img style="margin-right: 94px;" src="http://www.kdogisthebest.webege.com/images/plustab.png" id="image" onClick="menuanimate();"/>

<div id="loginoutbox" class="ablack" style="top:-20px;">
<div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 14px; padding-left: 20px;">Hello Guest!</div>
<a id="register" href="#fallr-register" class="button">Register</a> |
<a id="signin" href="#fallr-signin" class="button">Login</a>
</div>

</html>
```

This is not the prettiest but I think this is what you are looking for as far as the end result...